# Fixing overlapping vertexs caused by doing boolean

Tags: boolean-modifier

I used *Shrinkwrap* to paste a part of top of  head on a part of down of another head.
[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

And after that, I used boolean to merge with these parts into one object. But  weird texture came up.It seem there are overlapping vertices on original mesh.
[image: screenshot 3]

How can I fix and delete the overlapping vertices?

Blend files:

- [Blend 1031, as shown in the first screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmmqKHEN8ib3hGpVVhIOlVjiCcq-?e=SLxpVs)
- [Blend 1101, shrink-wrapped mask only](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmmqKHEN8ib3hHUYhDk8hW-ROq1j?e=gT25Jm)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149473/discussion-on-question-by-po-ex-fixing-overlapping-vertexs-caused-by-doing-boole); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.